# Change the counter in terms of date

Tags: date-time

If I have a post or submit a date-field, I would like the counter to say 'this is in 3 days time'.

i.e - on my site at the moment, (see here: http://www.universitycompare.com) I have dates for the latest open days.

Instead of displaying the date, It would be better to say, 'in 3 days time'. Is there a way to do this and if so how?

Answer (score 0):

Hope these plugins will be helpful

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/date-in-a-nice-tone/

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-relativedate

http://www.jasonhendriks.com/programmer/dynamic-dates/dynamic-dates-examples/